# when i try to move my picture with.Bottom keep getting error but i can move it with.Left and .Top

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

in Microsoft windows visual c# windows form application I keep getting this error message.

Error  1   Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Bottom' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

I can move the image with a int Control.Left or a Top but not a Bottom or Right what wrong with it

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Bottom += 1;

        }
```

Comment: You should use the Top and Left properties for relocating the picturebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom property is read only (as Right is).
You can however manipulate it's value indirectly by changing values of Top or Size properties.

Answer (score 1):

From [Control.Bottom Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bottom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> *The value of this property is equal to the sum of the Top property
>   value, and the Height property value.*
>
> **The Bottom property is a read-only property.** You can manipulate this
>   property value by changing the value of the Top or Height properties
>   or calling the SetBounds, SetBoundsCore, UpdateBounds, or
>   SetClientSizeCore methods.

Answer (score 0):

As error says, you cannot assign [Bottom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bottom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property - its calculated based on control size and location:

```
public int Bottom
{
    get { return this.y + this.height; }
}
```

And its for reading only. On the other hand, [Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.left%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.top%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will change bounds of control by changing it's `x` or `y` position:

```
public int Left
{
    get { return this.x; }
    set
    {
        SetBounds(value, this.y, this.width, this.height, BoundsSpecified.X);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your picture is a square, meaning you should easily be able to calculate the required `Top` and `Left` positions from the `Bottom` and `Right` you would like, together with the height and width of the picture.

Do that instead, and just use `Top` and `Left`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [Read my Blog Techhowdy][1]
// For right 
                pictureBox1.Top = ((Control)sender).Top;
                pictureBox1.Height = ((Control)sender).Height;
    // For bottom
                 pictureBox1.Left = ((Control)sender).Left;
                 pictureBox1.Width= ((Control)sender).Width;
    // For top
                 pictureBox1.Top= ((Control)sender).Top;
                 pictureBox1.Width = ((Control)sender).Width;

    // Casting it to Control will solve your problem - use Left as it can be manupilated


  [1]: http://techhowdy.com
```